# How do you ensure that the update of a PWA is an "atomic transaction"?

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

In a PWA I have a JavaScript array `installCache` with names of files to cache. And this code for updating:

```js
function addInstallListener() {
  self.addEventListener('install',
    event => {
      async function doIinstall() {
        try {
          await event.waitUntil(cache.addAll(installCache));
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("install event", err);
        }
      }
      event.waitUntil(doIinstall());
    }
  );
}
addInstallListener();
```

This does not work as I expect. I expect all the files listed to be installed on the client, but sometimes not all the files are updated.

The files are uploaded to the server (using `firebase deploy`), but the old version of a file may still be in the PWA cache in the browser.

(I am testing this in latest Chrome on Android and Windows 10.)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the behavior you describe by ensuring that the promise passed to `event.waitUntil()` rejects when there's a caching failure. Your current code wraps the `async` rejection in a `catch` block but then dosen't re-throw the error, so the overall promise will always end up fulfilling and never reject.

You can do this instead:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  const doInstall = async () => {
    try {
      const cache = await caches.open('my-cache-name');
      await cache.addAll(installCache);
    } catch (error) {
      // Do whatever logging you want.

      // Important: re-throw the error!
      throw error;
    }
  };

  event.waitUntil(doIinstall());
});
```

I'd suggest reading through https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#install for an overview of this stage of the service worker lifecycle.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That sounds very nice, I have totally missed the re-throw. So I should read "or rejects during install" as "or rejects during cache install event"? (That was not at all clear to me.)

Comment: Just to be sure about the details: Is there any reason you use "constant doInstall" instead of "function doInstall"?

Comment: Using an arrow function vs. `function` is just preference. You can do either. If anything that you want to ensure happens—caching, or anything else—make sure that the promise passed to event.waitUntil() rejects if that operation fails.

Comment: Thanks, then everything is clear. Except perhaps the documentation.

Comment: But. Unfortunately this did not help. I still see the same problem.

Comment: Like, you see the error being thrown, but the new service worker still finishes installation successfully and goes into the waiting phase?

Comment: It looks like that. I did not see any error. Right now I do not know if the was one. I think I will save the errors to localStorage (in the main thread) and investigate further.

Comment: Investigating a bit further under locahost (firebase serve). It is extremely buggy, but the bugs are hard to find. I am looking for work arounds and hope Google will address this soon (which I have been waiting for long now).